# EWS java api for programmatic access to Exhcange - opinions?

Tags: java, exchange-server

I am considering using EWS Java API to access Exchange. Specifically, to insert appointment into users' calendars. Now, the online documentation that I immediately find is... sparse, so I would very much appreciate if someone could give some input in:
1. Is this an API worth using? 
2. Are there any online resources for it (that a rather superficial google doesn't find)?
3. Is there anyone of the alternatives I should use instead? (SyncEx, j-exchange)

I've seen previously posted links to the alternatives. What I am hoping for, however, is that someone can share experience with what is actually good to work with.

Thanks a lot,

Håkan